# PHP exec() not executing

Tags: php, linux

I'm using a Raspberry Pi as a web server. I use [ouimeaux](http://ouimeaux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on it, so when I want to turn it on, I use `wemo switch name on`.

I've got a PHP file called 'wemo-on.php' which consists of:

```
<?php  
echo exec('wemo switch name on');
echo 'OK';
?>
```

However, when I browse to `http://pi/wemo-on.php`, I get `OK` but the script doesn't run at all. Just `OK`.

Things I've tried:

- Changing the exec() command to `sudo wemo switch name on`
- `chmod +x wemo-php`
- `chmod 777 wemo.php`
- Creating a batch file `wemo-on.sh` and calling that instead of the command itself

Still not working... :(

Any advice? I'm not exactly a pro at PHP/Linux, but I have been able to use `php exec()` on a Windows machine before without any drama.

Comment: use the output and return value parameters of `exec()` for debugging.

Comment: Checklist: is `wemo` available to the user running PHP? Is the script in the same directory as the script you posted here? What's the exit status (`exec('cmd', $fullResult, $status);`)? Is the last line of output just an empty line (`exec` returns only the last line of the `stdout`)? There are many, many things that could explain this behaviour. Make sure you check all of these things, and more

Comment: `wemo` should be available to all users. All files are in `~/www/`. 

I ran it with `$fullResult` and `$status` included...
`$fullResult` returns `Array ()` (not sure if I'm outputting this correctly?
`$status` returns `1`